# What other options are available into JSPDF's `html` method

Tags: javascript, jspdf

Whilst I was looking the documentation for `jspdf`'s `html` method (https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-html.html#~html)

I noticed that the function takes 2 parameters:

- `source`: That is the html code
- `options`: An object that has some options for the rendering.

So I wonder what `options` are available to fill the `options` object?

The only option I can see is the `callback` property of `options` object. Are there others and where I can find the documentation for them?

Comment: What makes you think there are others if they aren't in the api docs? Do you have a specific problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I try to make a pdf rendered nicer. I generate a pdf from html and dooes not take over the full width of the page. Thus I wanted to mess around a bit with the method's options in order to fix it.

Comment: So perhaps that should be the question instead? I hate to think lots of others haven't had same issue